# pass text box value to R File

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to pass the entered string value in text box to another R File named test.R on click of button

The passed value **ntext** is input to another variable in my test.R

**Server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {



  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {input$text})

  output$ntext <- renderText({ntext()

    assign('ntext',envir=.GlobalEnv)

    })
})
```

invisible(readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue"))
source("test.R")

**Ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sentiment Analysis"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("See current opinion around the globe " ),
      textInput("text", "Keyword"),
      actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),



      mainPanel(
           mainPanel(uiOutput('tweets_txt'))



    )
  )
))
```

**Test.R**

```
s<-searchTwitter(ntext(),100,lang="en")

df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(s, as.data.frame))
df$text <- sapply(df$text,function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))

#tweets_txt<-sapply(df$text,function(x) x$getText())

write.table(df$text,file="C:/Users/mtech/Desktop/Twitter/EXTRACT/SentiT/output.txt")

tweets_txt<-df$text
```

I edited the code as per your suggestions but value is not being passed to Test.R also value must be passed only after user entering the textbox thats the reason i included a invisible line to temporarily halt the execution

Please suggest

Comment: You can source the file `test.R` in your app and write a function in that file which would take `ntext` as input.

Comment: Tried it but ntext itself is not able to be identified as a variable in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said earlier in the comments, this seems to work

```
library(shiny)
source("test.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sentiment Analysis"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("See current opinion around the globe " ),
      textInput("text", "Keyword"),
      actionButton("goButton", "Go!")),

      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("ntext")
    )
  ))


  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {input$text})

    output$ntext <- renderText({ntext()
      testfunc(ntext())

      #assign('ntext',envir=.GlobalEnv)

    })
  })


  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My test.R file  is as shown below and it prints the text on the console:

```
testfunc <- function(texts){

  print(texts)
}
```

**[EDIT]:**

As per your edited code I have changed your server and Test.R file in a way that I think it should work.

The server is as follows:

```
source("Test.R")
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {input$text})

    output$tweets_txt <- renderText({

      searchInTwitter(ntext())
      ntext()
    })
  })
```

The Test.R is as follows:

```
searchInTwitter <- function(ntext){
  s<-searchTwitter(ntext,100,lang="en")

  df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(s, as.data.frame))
  df$text <- sapply(df$text,function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))

  #tweets_txt<-sapply(df$text,function(x) x$getText())

  write.table(df$text,file="C:/Users/mtech/Desktop/Twitter/EXTRACT/SentiT/output.txt")

  # tweets_txt<-df$text
}
```

Comment: it works fine tq but the thing is the keyword which comes from text box should in here searchTwitter(searchterm,100,lang="en") in place of searchterm but i am not able to

Comment: I  need the value from the text box to be transferred to **searchterm** in 'searchTwitter(searchterm,100,lang="en")' is what i am trying to achieve the above code only works as function rather than storing what is in the text box.

Comment: For **searchterm** to be transferred  in your search function you can just pass it as 'searchTwitter(ntext(),100,lang="en")'

Comment: ihave edited the code in question  tested with above code **Error in nchar: could not find function "ntext"
Stack trace (innermost first)**

Comment: my Test.R should run once user inputs in text box and click the button , As source(test.R) is written on top of server test.R runs without any input i.e **nothing is present in tnext on first run**

Comment: For that you can call `searchInTwitter(ntext())` inside `observeEevent` of your action button `goButton`.

Comment: another question can we have 2 **shinyServer(function(input, output)** in single server ?

Comment: No you cant. Maybe you should look at the concept of modularizing shiny app. Follow [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) link to know about modularizing your shiny app.